# Token Based Authentication AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. What I want is getting a token coming from a server with $http post and then use that token coming from the request to use as an authorization header for access in other page and following data requests to the server. Here is my existing code:

```
var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);


peopleApp.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // Change template tags
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

    // Enabling CORS
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    // $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});

peopleApp.controller('formController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.logIn = function(json, url){
        $http.post(url, json)
        .then(function(response){
            token = response.data.token;
            window.location.href = 'crew-menu';
        },function(response){
            alert('Please check the following validations on the next alert and contact the creators regarding this error');
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.errors));
        });

    }
});
```

P.S.
I am aware that this can be done by using the .run like this:

```
peopleApp.run(function($http) {
     $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'YmVlcDpib29w';
});
```

However the token Authorization will be coming from a login authentication via post request

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Take the token from login response and save it somewhere in the app, most common solution is to store it in local storage so it will be available after browser restart.

```
$scope.logIn = function(json, url){
        $http.post(url, json)
        .then(function(response){
            localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.data.token });

            window.location.href = 'crew-menu';
        },function(response){
            alert('Please check the following validations on the next alert and contact the creators regarding this error');
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.errors));
        });

    }
```

**Step 2**

Use angularjs $http interceptor to automatically add authentication header to every http request:

```
app.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', function ($q, $location, localStorageService) {

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    var _request = function (config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

Or put it manualy every time you make http request:

```
function buildConfig() {
    var c = {};
    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        c.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    }

    return c;
}
function post(url, model) {
    return $http.post(url, model, buildConfig());
}
```

More info: [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)  and
[my angular webapi project](https://github.com/jabiel/webapi.js/blob/master/webapi.js)

Comment: This is a good solution too. But I did the $window.localstorage approach. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it. The solution is to store the token in a localstorage first then use run function for it be a default. Here is the code:

```
var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);


peopleApp.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // Change template tags
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

    // Enabling CORS
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    // $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});

peopleApp.controller('formController', function($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    $scope.logIn = function(json, url){
        $http.post(url, json)
        .then(function(response){
            token = response.data.token;
            $window.localStorage.token = token;
            window.location.href = 'crew-menu';
        },function(response){
            alert('Please check the following validations on the next alert and contact the creators regarding this error');
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.errors));
        });

    }
});

peopleApp.run(function($window, $http){
    if ($window.localStorage.token){
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Token "+$window.localStorage.token;
    }
});
```